# High CPU load sorting by a property with sorted()

Tags: python, django, sorting

The operation `sorted()` consumes a lot of CPU and the app is using it to order by a property for each user every 5 seconds (It's a table that is modifiyng continously)

What do you think that it would be the best way to optimize this operation? 
Change the property by a field and update it every 5 seconds would be an option?

Comment: do you have control on the app and the code which calls `sort` ? if so could you post it?

Answer (score 0):

If your table are in the db, you probably better sort with SQL tools (which most of the time would be faster because fields are indexed) through Django's queryset (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
my_sorted_table = MyModel.objects.all().order_by('my_order_field')
```

However, if you specify how and what for you are using your table that you order constantly, we would be able to give better answers.

Comment: I cannot use order_by because it's not a field, it's a property that returns an integer.

Answer (score 0):

As Fian suggested, SQL is pretty optimised in sorting and data processing. Try to restrict process intensive methods to SQL or use pandas to sort data at the application level.

Adding to Fian's answer, for ascending order by field, use "field_name" in the order_by method and '-field_name'(with a -) in the order_by field.

```
my_sorted_table = Model.objects.all().order_by('field')
my_sorted_table = Model.objects.all().order_by('-field')
```

Comment: Thanks @rahul-reddy-vemireddy, but the reason of use sorted is that the app is not sorting by a field, is a property that returns an integer.

Comment: You should show the code of that property, maybe there's a way to calculate it in the db.